# Set of discontinuity closed? Integrability and null set.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be defined and bounded on $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$, let $D$ be its set of discontinuities. I want to prove if $D$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ then $f$ is Riemann-integrable.

My approach is that I want to prove $D$ is compact, which reduce to $D$ being closed. If $D$ compact then $D$ has Jordan measure $0$, which means $f$ is Riemann-integrable. I proved everything but I get stuck at $D$ is closed (or $[a,b]\backslash$ is open), I am wondering whether this statement is true to begin with, if so please help me a bit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let your interval be $I = [0,1]$, and let $D = \mathbb{Q}\cap I$. Then $D$ has Lebesgue measure $0$, but $D$ is neither closed nor open, so $D$ is not compact. Your proof will have to use a different approach, it appears.

Comment: you are definitely right. Do you know any method? I don't want to use oscillation criterion

Comment: I'm not personally familiar with another method, but this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244580/the-lebesgue-criterion-for-riemann-integrability-with-no-oscillations has a response that shows a method without oscillations for a function valued in a Banach space. Perhaps you can model your proof on that?

Comment: This is great. Thank you.