# Example showing the subspace of Riemann integrable functions in $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ is not closed

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral, fourier-series

In Stein and Shakarski, they say "For instance, as we
have already indicated, the subspace of Riemann integrable functions
in $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ is not closed."

Can anybody give me an example of such a sequence?

Comment: Perhaps: show the subspace is dense, but not the whole thing.  Indeed, do you perhaps you know an orthonormal basis for $L_2$ consisting of continuous functions?

Comment: @KennyWong: your (deleted) approach was indeed extremely similar to mine, you just missed to give a positive measure to your Cantor set :D

Answer (score 2):

I am going to transform my comments into an answer.

Let $C_n$ be the closed set that we have at the $n$-th step of the construction of a [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) $C$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$ and let $f_n=\chi_{C_n}$. $f_n$ is Riemann-integrable and square-integrable and $f_n\to \chi_C$ in $L^2$.
However, $\chi_C$ is not Riemann-integrable due to the [Lebesgue criterion for Riemann integrability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163367/lebesgues-criterion-for-riemann-integrability-of-banach-space-valued-functions): the set of discontinuities of $\chi_C$ has positive measure.

Comment: Sorry, I read the first two sentences and not the third before making my comment. Carry on! +1.

Answer (score 0):

Also one can do: let $\mathbb{Q}=\{q_{1},q_{2},...\}$. Put $f_{N}(x)=1_{\{q_{1},...,q_{N}\}}(x)$. Each $f_{n}$ is riemman integrable but $f_{n}\to_{\|\cdot\|_{L^{2}}}1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ (it is easy to show that $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is not riemman integrable).

Comment: This actually does not work properly, because in the sense of $L^2$ all of the $f_N$ and $f$ are the zero function (because of modding out by a.e. equivalence).

Comment: @Ian: I guess that depends on the intended meaning of $L^2$ (or $\mathcal{L}^2$) as a space of true functions or as a space of equivalence classes of functions.

Comment: Anyway, Riemann is a person, so please state his name with a capital letter!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio In the "functions" situation you still have a problem, because this sequence converges in $L^2$ norm to *any* function that is zero a.e., many of which are indeed Riemann integrable.

Comment: then what "functions" of $L^{2}$ are Riemman integrable? is it even well defined?

Comment: It's sort of the other way around: there are elements of $L^2$ with no Riemann integrable representative, but there are no elements of $L^2$ with all Riemann integrable representatives. My point was that a good answer to this question would be a class with no Riemann integrable representative.